# Method for dividing rests after a weighted arithmetic mean

Tags: statistics, arithmetic

Suppose I have to divide $10$ indivisible parts between three parties.
Each party has a certain "weight", suppose they are $5:2:4$ (together $11$).
The weights mean that the best division is to award each party a $5/11:2/11:4/11$ share.
So e.g. $11$ indivisible parts must be divided as $5:2:4$.
What would be the rule to take $1$ away from one of them?
I can divide the $10$ as:
$4,2,4$
$5,2,3$
$5,1,4$
$6,1,3$
etc.

Which is best and which mathematical calculation describes it?

Comment: Which is best depends on what you mean by "best". Also, it's not clear what the weights have to do with the problem.

Comment: Anyway, the US has this problem after each census, where the 438 members of the House of Representatives are to be allocated to the 50 states in proportion to the populations of the states. Congress has argued for over 200 years about how to do this. You might enjoy reading up on this problem.